Laws of noncommutative random variables
Background: Let $\mathbb C\langle X_1,\dots,X_m\rangle$ denote the algebra of noncommutative polynomials in $m$ indeterminates (i.e. the free unital $\mathbb C$-algebra). You define an anti-linear involution on $\mathbb C\langle X_1,\dots,X_m\rangle$ by $(X_{i_1}\dots X_{i_n})^\ast=X_{i_n}\dots X_{i_1}$, making $\mathbb C\langle X_1,\dots,X_m\rangle$ into a unital $\ast$-algebra.
The universal property of $\mathbb C\langle X_1,\dots,X_m\rangle$ implies that whenever $x_1,\dots,x_m$ are self-adjoint elements of a von Neumann algebra $M$, there exists a unique $\ast$-homomorphism $\pi\colon \mathbb C\langle X_1,\dots,X_m\rangle\to M$ such that $\pi(X_i)=x_i$ for $1\leq i\leq m$. If $\varphi$ is a normal state on $M$, one calls $\varphi\circ \pi$ the law of the $m$-tuple $(x_1,\dots,x_m)$ under $\varphi$.
It is known that a linear functional $\lambda$ on $\mathbb C\langle X_1,\dots,X_m\rangle$ is the law of some $m$-tuple under some normal state if and only if it is positive ($\lambda(P^\ast P)\geq 0$ for all $P\in\mathbb C\langle X_1,\dots,X_m\rangle$), unital ($\lambda(1)=1$) and exponentially bounded (there exists $R>0$ s.t. $\lvert\lambda(X_{i_1}\dots X_{i_n})\rvert\leq R^n$ for all $i_1,\dots,i_n\in\mathbb N$). Moreover, it is the law of some $m$-tuple under a tracial state if it is additionally cyclic ($\lambda(PQ)=\lambda(QP)$ for all $P,Q\in\mathbb C\langle X_1,\dots,X_m\rangle$).
Question: When is $\lambda$ the law of a faithful normal state?

I’m not sure if this is what you seek, but a sufficient condition is that $\lambda$ is cyclic (since any nondegenerate tracial state is automatically faithful), and a necessary condition is that, for any $P\in\mathbb{C}\langle X_1,\cdots,X_n\rangle$, $\lambda(P^\ast P) = 0$ implies $\lambda(Q^\ast P^\ast PQ) = 0$ for all $Q\in\mathbb{C}\langle X_1,\cdots,X_n\rangle$ (this can be shown by examining the GNS construction associated to $\lambda$). I’m pretty sure the second condition is not sufficient though.

@DavidGao Yes, I am aware of that. I am specifically interested in the case of non-tracial states because you'd like to have laws that give rise to modular groups (on the full von Neumann algebra). And I also think that your necessary condition is not sufficient (although I haven't tried hard to find explicit counterexamples).

The actual equivalent condition would be for any $P\in\pi_\lambda(\mathbb{C}\langle X_1,\cdots,X_n\rangle)’’$, $\lambda(P^\ast P) = 0$ implies $\lambda(Q^\ast P^\ast PQ) = 0$ for all $Q\in\mathbb{C}\langle X_1,\cdots,X_n\rangle$. As a purely technical matter you can rewrite that in terms of a net - for any net $(P_i)\subset\mathbb{C}\langle X_1,\cdots,X_n\rangle$ s.t. $\sup_i\sup_{Q\in\mathbb{C}\langle X_1,\cdots,X_n\rangle, \lambda(Q^\ast Q)>0}\frac{\lambda(Q^\ast P_i^\ast P_iQ)}{\lambda(Q^\ast Q)}<\infty$, …

… and $\lambda(Q^\ast P_i^\ast P_iQ)$ converges for all $Q\in\mathbb{C}\langle X_1,\cdots,X_n\rangle$, we have $\lim_i\lambda(P_i^\ast P_i)=0$ implies $\lim_i\lambda(Q^\ast P_i^\ast P_iQ)=0$ for all $Q\in\mathbb{C}\langle X_1,\cdots,X_n\rangle$. But that seems overly cumbersome to be a meaningful condition.

(The difficulty might lie in the fact that the set of faithful states is neither open nor closed in all states. Though it does have dense interior if I’m not mistaken. Actually, this sort of reminds of the fact that it’s hard to characterize diagonalizable matrices among all matrices.)

(Thinking again, it shouldn’t even have dense interior in general. It’s just the entire set that’s dense.)

Thank you for your comments. I also think that this reformulation in terms of the GNS rep. is probably not very helpful, although it's of course always good to know that it can be done. Thinking about the question more in terms of modular theory, I realized that one may want to allow for non-selfadjoint elements in the non-tracial case (then at least the laws for which the $X_j$ are "eigenvectors of the modular group" should be realized by faithful states).
